# Open Jupyter notebook without using terminal command on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using the Jupyter notebook a lot, so I would like to make opening it as short and as easy as possible. Is there a way to avoid opening it by typing "Jupiter notebook" in the terminal? Is there some short key? (I am using it on Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [double click to open an ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953227/double-click-to-open-an-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned similar and helpful questions to this one are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953227/double-click-to-open-an-ipython-notebook) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158893/open-an-ipython-notebook-via-double-click-on-osx). I tried to use on my new Mac the package [nbopen](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen), that other users have reported to do the job, but I couldn't manage to make it work properly. Eventually, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32790448/5838180) brought me the desired solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want, you can put this in your ~/.bashrc file

```
jupyter notebook
```

Each time you open a terminal, that command will execute automatically.
So, the first time would be okay but if you open up more terminals, that command will get executed each time.

However if you really want, you can write a script that will only execute that command if jupyter is not already running. (Use ps and grep for jupyter). If you do that, replace that 'jupyter notebook' line in your .bashrc with the name of your script.

Comment: I see that starting jupyter from the console is the most straightforward way, everything else is more cumbersome. I will stick to console. But thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

How about an alias? Edit your bash profile and set an alias for jupyter notebook e.g. `alias jpy="jupyter notebook"`. You can even specify notebooks for direct opening of a specific file, I think.