# Make Jupyter Notebook clickable

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I did develop an application for several users on windows, without internet access using python and **Jupyter Notebook as a graphical interface.** 
The application intend to process some data, they just have to copy paste the path to their datafile and run through different step.

As a user they just want to double click somewhere to open it. I may not fully understand Jupyter Notebook but I would like to find a simple way to make the notebook clickable ...

Could you help me ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [nteract](https://nteract.io/desktop)? It was a suggestion in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021819/8508004), that was linked from [a question with a similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30953227/8508004) as yours, but referenced the previous version of the tech that is now Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thax, I will look at all your answer but: the point is also that it should run without any web dependency. I will edit my question.