# How do I associate ipynb files with jupyter in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter

Right now, in order to open a ipynb file in ubuntu, I need to open the terminal and start the jupyter notebook in my web browser.
Is there a way to open directly a .ipynb file by double clicking on it? I cannot find jupyter in the "open with other application" menu .

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to: [double click to open an ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953227/double-click-to-open-an-ipython-notebook). Look for the second most voted answer (as of aug 20th, 2021). There you will find a step by step procedure on how to achieve this.

Comment: "Second most voted answer" is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489884/1168212 ? Number of votes could change with time