# I'm trying to launch a 'jupyter notebook' by making a clickable shell script on osx 10.14

Tags: shell, terminal, jupyter

I want to make a file that will 
-open terminal and execute 'jupyter notebook' in the command line.

I am running Mac osx 10.14 (Mojave) I have jupyter notebook tested operational. Any pointers would help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from another thread that will work for the time being.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995543/12496767

I'll probably be adding more specific requirements later and updating this thread as it develops.