# Open .ipynb in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook on double-click (macOS)

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've been trying to figure out how I can open a .ipynb file on double-click on a Mac, so the file opens with Anaconda and then automatically opens Jupyter Notebook with the file contents.

I have tried creating an application through Automator that opens with a jupyter_lab command, but the issue is that Jupyter lives in Anaconda, so this method is not working. See these articles for my steps: https://samedwardes.com/2020-01-31-open-ipynb-with-double-click/ and [Open an ipython notebook via double-click on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158893/open-an-ipython-notebook-via-double-click-on-osx)

I have also tried installing `nbopen` with the following:

`python3 -m pip install nbopen`

This works, and then I can run `nbopen file.ipynb` through the terminal, but I want to be able to bypass this step and do it while in file explorer, physically looking at the file instead.

I have ran the recommended command for osx to integrate it with file manager `./osx-install.sh` but I just get `zsh no such file or directory` and can't really find any help with figuring out why this is pushing back an error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this "convenience issue" as well, and didn't go for the nbopen route, but instead, I just made a batch script (I named it jupyter-notebook.bat) that calls certain conda functions, and pretty much initiates things like how double clicking works. In the script, I just have this:

```
call "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
call conda activate myEnvironment
call python C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py %1
```

Lastly you just need to configure that every .ipynb opens up using your jupyter-notebook.bat script.

For consistency, I placed the script in my Anaconda folder. And if you also have nb_conda_kernels installed in your base environment, you'd have access to the other environment you've created as well from there.

Comment: "Lastly you just need to configure that every .ipynb opens up using your jupyter-notebook.bat script." how would you do that ?

Comment: If it's on Windows, I meant by opening the file's properties and changing "Open File WIth" and enter the batch command's path.