# How can I create a desktop shortcut for Jupyter Notebook(Anaconda) on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am new to Jupyter Notebook. I mainly use it for my Python class. I installed Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda. So, to open Jupyter Notebook, I have to open the anaconda navigator every time. Is there any way to bypass this in MacOS and open Notebook directly?
I have tried making a terminal shell script with the following code

```
/Users/utkarsharyan/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-6.4.2-py38hecd8cb5_0/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
```

But it gave this error

```
(base) utkarsharyan@Utkarshs-MacBook-Air ~ % /Users/utkarsharyan/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-6.4.2-py38hecd8cb5_0/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
/Users/utkarsharyan/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-6.4.2-py38hecd8cb5_0/bin/jupyter_mac.command: /Users/utkarsharyan/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-6.4.2-py38hecd8cb5_0/bin/jupyter-notebook: /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/09f385b3-041f-4619-6576-50f6b5465a28/volume: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

What should I do?

Comment: [This](https://samedwardes.com/post/2020-01-31-open-ipynb-with-double-click/) may be helpful.

Comment: i don't know how it works on macos, but try running `jupyter` from the console. or `python jupyter`

Answer (score 1):

#### Jupyter notebooks "app":

There are many ways you might go about doing this. All of them will be more or less complicated to do because Jupyter itself isn't built to be used as a desktop app.

If you want to try a few DIY ways, this one has a few answers that might be helpful: [Open an ipython notebook via double-click on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158893/open-an-ipython-notebook-via-double-click-on-osx)

If you prefer not to deal with extra complications, a **mac app for Jupyter** would be your best bet.

#### Desktop app for Jupyter: [Callisto](https://callistoapp.com)

It's made for macOS and iOS. Super easy to use with Jupyter notebooks and Python. It's currently in the beta stage so it's definitely something you can try for a Python class.